# Is it possible to write monolog logs outside of the symfony project directory?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

I am using symfony 4.1 and monolog 3.3.
I have my symfony project in the following directory: `/var/www/html/{project_dir}`.
In production environment I want my logs to be stored inside `/tmp/foo` instead of standard symfony directory: `{project_dir_path}/var/log`.

I changed `Kernel::getLogDir()` method to the following:

```php
public function getLogDir()
{
    return 'prod' === $this->environment
        ? '/tmp/foo'
        : $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log';
}
```

My production `monolog.yaml` path looks like this:

```
path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
```

My environment for testing issues is set to 'prod'.

When I am debugging, I can see that monolog's log directory is correctly set to `/tmp/foo`. `/tmp/foo` has proper access rights (0766) but when I try to log something, the directory contains nothing.

Comment: You must provide a full verified path for this line  /tmp/foo , this will give you the path ```php $fullVerifiedPath = getcwd(); ```

Comment: The full verified path is `/tmp/foo`.

Comment: concatenate DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant at the end of the path String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, simple mistake. I was developing on docker container, having my project directory as a volumine, but `/tmp/foo` wasn't obviously binded, so logs were just sitting on the container.

Comment: Yes, correct. With Docker, especially in production, you are supposed to redirect to `php://sterr` (as monolog `path`) instead of a file, so that you can use `docker logs -f ....` to recover logs, and ignore the fact that the file is ephemeral among different containers.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you can't for security reason. 
But, you can bypass it by creating a symlink inside your project directory for the right directory folder.

Something like:

```
public function getLogDir()
{
    return 'prod' === $this->environment
        ? '/var/symlink-to-tmp-folder'
        : $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log';
}
```